# Flutter FireStore in ListView with DropDown Filter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to get data from `firestore`  in my `Listview`,

**But,**
By selecting something from the drop-down menu I would like to display the names of the collections in the `Listview`.

That's all I want now, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this package **[dropdown_search](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search)**

Add this to your package's `pubspec.yaml file`:

```
dependencies:
  dropdown_search:
```

**Import**

```
import 'package:dropdown_search/dropdown_search.dart';
```

**Simple implementation**

```
  DropdownSearch<String>(
    mode: Mode.MENU,
    showSelectedItem: true,
    items: ["Brazil", "Italia (Disabled)", "Tunisia", 'Canada'],
    label: "Menu mode",
    hint: "country in menu mode",
    popupItemDisabled: (String s) => s.startsWith('I'),
    onChanged: print,
    selectedItem: "Brazil"),
```

You can learn more about this package **[here](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search)**

> Flutter simple and robust DropdownSearch with item search feature,
> making it possible to use an offline item list or filtering URL for
> easy customization.

[image]